# Data encryption in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, encryption

I am working on a project where I need to encrypt the data which I store in my .plist file and want to send encrypted data to my webServices too.
I am wondering that is there any framework available in iOS that will help me in implementing encryption.

I have heard that iOS automatically do some encryption at its level.

As in .net we have RSA and other encryption libraries pre written, do we have same in iOS??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS provide a library or you can call it a framework for encryption.
you can have have both Symmetric and Asymmetric encryption in iOS. `CommonCryptor.h` is the file you need to look for. you can check apple documentation also for more detail, Encryption in iOS is been explained in detail in Apple documents.

i hope it helped!!

Answer (score 2):

The Apple docs can be quite complicated to digest when you don't know much about encryption. Since you will be using it then you definitely want to get informed but here's a library that allows to encrypt/decrypt in many different ways at a higher level. It's VERY comprehensive and they offer a 30-day trial. I wasted many hours trying to understand the Apple docs until I found this and in half an hour I've already applied it to my app.

Check out the Encryption and RSA sections. 
http://www.chilkatsoft.com/encryption-features.asp

Note: I'm not the author of this lib but I have used it with happy results. And yes, the price is not cheap but the lib definitely well worth it.